# Study or business visa for a paid internship in The Netherlands?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, netherlands, work, study

I'm an Indian student who will be going to The Netherlands in the summer for a paid internship of 3 months. My travel agent told me that I would need a business visa. However, I'm wondering if a study visa would be more appropriate.

The reason I would prefer a study visa is to avoid paying the business visa fee. Is a study visa only applicable when one enrolls at a Dutch university to take courses?

Which visa should I get to do an internship in The Netherlands?

Comment: What will be the duration of your stay in The Netherlands? Are you enrolled as a student during the internship?

Comment: The duration of my internship will be 3 months. I have been registered as an "exchange student".

Comment: Please add this information to your question by [editing](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/43278/edit) it.

Answer (score 5):

As you will not be staying more than 3 months you will need a [short stay (Schengen) visa](http://www.government.nl/issues/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/short-stay-visas-for-the-netherlands). These visas are also called VKV (acronym for Visum Kort Verblijf in Dutch) or Type C visas and cost €60.

Because you are an Indian citizen your internship provider also needs to arrange [a work permit for you](http://www.studyinholland.nl/study-options/internship/internship-as-part-of-a-programme-abroad) (Tewerkstellingsvergunning, or TWV in Dutch).

You might find [this document](http://www.studyinholland.nl/documentation/immigration-procedures-for-international-students-doing-an-internship.pdf) provided by Nuffic useful as it has more information on doing an internship in The Netherlands.